# How to deal with component constructor race conditions in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, asynchronous

I'm trying to get to grips with Angular 4. However, a race condition between two component constructors seems to be preventing the page from loading correctly.

I have two components - a page component, and an article component, which is nested inside.

Inside the page component, I subscribe to an activatedRoute.queryParams object to get the "?id=1" get parameter when it becomes available. When it is, I set the articleId property of the page component.

```
import { Injectable, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ArticleOrm } from '../../../klass/orm/one/articleOrm';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-article',
    templateUrl: './article.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./article.component.css']
})
@Injectable()
export class ArticleComponent {
    articleId;
    constructor(
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
    ) {
        this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
            this.articleId = params.id;
        });
    }
}
```

In the page component view file, I include the component for the article module itself, passing in the gleaned articleId as an input parameter.

```
<div class="com-article">
    <single-article [articleId]="articleId"></single-article>
</div>
```

In the article component, the constructor creates an new article ORM object. This is a bespoke ORM solution. Calling this.article.get() returns an RxJS observable, I believe.

```
import { Input, Injectable, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ArticleOrm } from '../../../klass/orm/one/articleOrm';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'single-article',
    templateUrl: './singleArticle.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./singleArticle.component.css']
})
@Injectable()
export class SingleArticleComponent {
    @Input() articleId;
    article: ArticleOrm;
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ) {
        var scope = this;
        this.article = new ArticleOrm(this.articleId, {
            http: scope.http
        });
        var observable = this.article.get();
    }
}
```

The Orm class looks like this...

```
export class ArticleOrm {
    ...
    get() {
        let fullUrl = this.getUrl + '?id=' + this.identifier;
        var obs = this.http.get(fullUrl);
        obs.subscribe((res) => {
            this.properties = res.response;
            this.identifier = res.response.id;
        });
        return obs;
    }
    ...
}
```

And then the single article component view looks like this:

```
<h1>{{ article.properties.short_descr }}</h1>
<ul>
    <li>{{ article.properties.resource.created_at }}</li>
    <li>{{ article.properties.resource.updated_at }}</li>
</ul>
<div>
    {{ article.properties.content }}
</div>
```

I think I need to get hold of the id get parameter first, before I then do the ajax call that loads the article data. However, I am unsure how to do this. What is the best strategy for managing this type of async dependency between components when using Angular 4?

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn more about the lifecycle of components.

An input, like `articleId`, will never, ever be available in the constructor: angular needs to construct the component, by calling the constructor, before it can possibly set its fields decorated with `@Input`.

So, if you want to know the initial value of an input, you need to do that in the `ngOnInit()` lifecycle hook.

In this case, if the queryParams of the activated route in the parent change, then the articleId will get a new value. If that's a possibility (i.e. the parent route links to itself with a different query param, for example), you thus need to react to the changes in the input. This can be done using the `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook.

All this is described in [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

You also definitely need to learn about dependency injection. Instead of creating an ArticleOrm object in the component, you should make it a service, and inject it in the component. That's what makes your code testable (and idiomatic).